# Boolean Field for django_filter search bar

Tags: django, filter, django-forms, django-filter, django-filters

I am trying to show an option on a search bar where the user can choose a `True` or `False` value for the boolean fields `lead_register`(and `finished_leveltest`) below.

```
class LevelTestFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = LevelTest
        fields = {
            'first_name': ['icontains'],
            'username': ['icontains'],
            'phone_number': ['icontains'],
            'email': ['exact'],
            'lead_register': ['exact'],
            'finished_leveltest': ['exact'],
        }
```

Right now, I typed in `exact` because I didn't know what to put there. I hope you guys could help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This should work as it is. If the model field is a `BooleanField` then django-filter would automatically use `BooleanFilter` unless you specify something. Did you try running this?

Comment: Yes, I did. However, I just get a blank pull down choice field on the actual website.

Comment: Please show your model `LevelTest`. Are `lead_register` and `finished_leveltest` by any chance fields with `choices`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Not really. The fields are models.BooleanField(defualt=False) for each.

Comment: sorry mate did you solved the issue? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

See https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#overriding-default-filters

You can override all the form's booleans by adding `filter_overrides` to your `Meta`:

```py
class LevelTestFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = LevelTest
        fields = {
            'first_name': ['icontains'],
            'username': ['icontains'],
            'phone_number': ['icontains'],
            'email': ['exact'],
            'lead_register': ['exact'],
            'finished_leveltest': ['exact'],
        }
        filter_overrides = {
            models.BooleanField: {
                'filter_class': django_filters.BooleanFilter,
                'extra': lambda f: {
                    'widget': forms.CheckboxInput,
                },
            },
        }
```

Alternately, you can just customize individual fields, which is useful if you're modifying most of them in one way or another:

```py
class LevelTestFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    lead_register__exact = django_filters.BooleanFilter(
        field_name='lead_register',
        label='A more expressive label',
        lookup_expr='exact',
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput,
    )
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = LevelTest
        fields = {
            'first_name': ['icontains'],
            'username': ['icontains'],
            'phone_number': ['icontains'],
            'email': ['exact'],
            'lead_register': ['exact'],
            'finished_leveltest': ['exact'],
        }
```

Comment: When I use either options, I get the error 'models'is not defined and 'forms' is not defined respectively.

Comment: Make sure you're importing django.forms or django.models.  I don't know what your imports look like at the top of the file.